# How do I overwrite a row vector in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to normalize each row vector of numpy array x, but I'm facing 2 problems.

1. I'm unable to update the row vectors of x (source code in image)
2. Is it possible to avoid the for loop (line 6) with any numpy functions?

   ```
   import numpy as np
   x = np.array([[0, 3, 4] , [1, 6, 4]])
   c = x ** 2
   for i in range(0, len(x)):
       print(x[i]/np.sqrt(c[i].sum())) #prints [0. 0.6 0.8]
       x[i] = x[i]/np.sqrt(c[i].sum())
       print(x[i]) #prints [0 0 0]
       print(x) #prints [[0 0 0] [0 0 0]] and wasn't updated
   ```

I've just recently started out with numpy, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: post code, not an image

Comment: Try `x = np.array([[0,3,4],[1,6,4]],dtype=np.float32)`

Comment: @Siladittya Thank you, that worked great!

Comment: And you can't accept more than one answer :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. I'm unable to update the row vectors of x (source code in image)

Your `np.array` has no `dtype` argument, so it uses `<type 'numpy.int32'>`. If you wish to store floats in the array, add a `float dtype`:

```
x = np.array([
        [0,3,4],
        [1,6,4]
        ], dtype = np.float)
```

---

To see this, compare

```
    x = np.array([
            [0,3,4],
            [1,6,4]
            ], dtype = np.float)
    print type(x[0][0])   # output = <type 'numpy.float64'>
```

to

```
    x = np.array([
            [0,3,4],
            [1,6,4]
            ])
    print type(x[0][0])   # output = <type 'numpy.int32'>
```

---

> is it possible to avoid the for loop (line 6) with any numpy functions?

This is how I would do it:

```
norm1, norm2 = np.linalg.norm(x[0]), np.linalg.norm(x[1])
print x[0] / norm1
print x[1] / norm2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
x/np.sqrt((x*x).sum(axis=1))[:, None]
```

Example:

```
In [9]: x = np.array([[0, 3, 4] , [1, 6, 4]])

In [10]: x/np.sqrt((x*x).sum(axis=1))[:, None]
Out[10]: 
array([[0.        , 0.6       , 0.8       ],
       [0.13736056, 0.82416338, 0.54944226]])
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first question:
`x = np.array([[0,3,4],[1,6,4]],dtype=np.float32)`

For the second question:
`x/np.sqrt(np.sum(x**2,axis=1).reshape((len(x),1)))`

Answer (score 0):

Given 2-dimensional array

```
x = np.array([[0, 3, 4] , [1, 6, 4]])
```

Row-wise L2 norm of that array can be calculated with:

```
norm = np.linalg.norm(x, axis = 1)
print(norm)
[5.         7.28010989]
```

You can not divide array x of shape (2, 3) by norm of shape (2,), the following trick enables that by adding extra dimension to norm

```
# Divide by adding extra dimension
x = x / norm[:, None]
print(x)

[[0.         0.6        0.8       ]
[0.13736056 0.82416338 0.54944226]]
```

This solves both your questions

Comment: Please explain your answer.